# Don't show error for self signed certificates in local network

Tags: node.js, https, openssl

I have a nodejs server that runs inside my network, and for security issues, there is no access to the internet.
The application needs to run in https, so I created a self-signed certificate and added it to my nodejs server:

```
const options = {
    key: await fs.readFile(key, 'utf-8'),
    cert: await fs.readFile(cert, 'utf-8'),
  };
  servers.https = https.createServer(options, this.app);
```

All this works fine, except when I open the app in the browser, I get a "Your connection is not private" warning, and the user needs to click "Advanced" and then "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" to access the app.
[image]

What do I need to do so that the user does not receive this warning?

I understand the reasoning behind the warning, to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks, but because everything is running locally on my network, this is not a risk.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This warning can not be disabled when using self signed certificates.

One possibility would be to use a local DNS and issue a Let's Encrypt certificate for it.